# Argument error - cannot convert from interface to class

Tags: c#, class, oop, interface

I have the following interfaces below which are used by 2 different classes.

```
    public interface IDiversRepository
        {
            IGroupsRepository GroupsManager { get; set; }
            List<Diver> Divers {get;} 
            void AddDiver(Diver aDiver);
            Diver GetDiver(uint regNumber);
            void LoadDivers(string fileName, string delimiter);
            void SaveDivers(string fileName, string delimiter);
        }
    
    public interface IGroupsRepository
        {
            List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
            void AddGroup(Group aGroup);
            Group GetGroup(uint regNumber);
            void LoadGroups(string fileName, string delimiter);
            void SaveGroups(string fileName, string delimiter);
    
        }
```

I have the classes below which implements these interfaces.

```
  public class DiversManager : IDiversRepository
    {

        public IGroupsRepository GroupsManager { get; set; }
        public List<Diver> Diver { get; }


        public void AddDiver(Diver aDiver)
        {
            //some code
        }
  
        public Diver GetDiver(uint regNumber)
        {

            //some code
        }

        public void LoadDivers(string fileName, string delimiter)
        {
            //some code
        }      

        public void SaveDivers(string fileName, string delimiter)
        {
           //some code
        }

   }

public class GroupsManager : IGroupsRepository
{
        public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public void AddGroup(Group aGroup);
        {
           //some code
        }
        public Group GetGroup(uint regNumber);
        {
           //some code
        }
        public void LoadGroups(string fileName, string delimiter);
        {
           //some code
        }
        public void SaveGroups(string fileName, string delimiter);
        {
           //some code
        }

}
```

I am getting an error "Argument 1: cannot convert from IGroupsRepository to GroupsManager on this part of the code on my main program. Am I missing something with regard to the implementation of the interfaces which causes this error? Without changing the code in the main program, how can I resolve this error? Thank you.

```
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        IGroupsRepository grpMngr = new GroupsManager();
        IDiversRepository divMngr = new DiversManager(grpMngr); //error points to grpMngr
      }
     }
```

Comment: While all `GroupsManager` objects will be `IGroupsRepository`, not all `IGroupsRepository` objects will be a `GroupsManager`. You cannot cast like that, and if you are trying to do it, then there is a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have a constructor in `DiversManager`that takes an `IGroupsRepository` as an argument. You should add a constructor like this:

```
public DiversManager(IGroupsRepository groupsRepository) {
    // some code
}
```